# Angular JS : why {{objA.objB.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}} takes much time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, batarang

In `AngularJS` tab of Chrome dev tools (I'm using `AngularJS Batarang` (Stable)). I have the following lines, describing which watch expressions took the highest time to evaluate (if an expression called several times, the evaluation time is added)

```
{{objA.objB.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}} | 20.1% | 1009ms
{{objA.objB.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm'}} | 22.8% | 1148ms
```

The question is why such an evaluation takes so much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's "normal" for Angular because Angular runs every single filter (including the date filter) twice per $digest cycle once something has changed. This takes it's toll on the performance. The first run is from the $$watchers detecting any changes, the second run is to see if there are further changes that need updated values.

If you can change your DOM filter:

```
{{objA.objB.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}}
```

to use a $filter provider, which you can use to run filters in your controller before parsing them into the DOM you preprocess your data before sending it to the view, which avoids the step of parsing the DOM and understanding the inline filter syntax:

```
$scope.theDate = $filter('date')(objA.objB.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
```

Comment: So you're trying to say that all `filters` are dead slow?

Comment: Not really. But each of them goes through the same process. Depends on a lot of things ie. the amount of filters used.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that a lot of things affect the performance of AngularJS apps. If performance becomes an issue you can Google how to improve the performance of your AngularJS app. There's a lot of great articles on the subject.